# How to create a sitemap in sitefinity CMS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitefinity

Please give me sample or links how to create sitemap in Sitefinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Sitemap Generator here (free): http://enterprisefinity.com/products/sitefinity-sitemap-generator/

But you should also be familiar with some of the challenges of creating an all-purpose sitemap generator in Sitefinity.  Each piece of content has no set page where it should appear - that depends on the configuration of widgets within your site.  So it's difficult to build a solution that understands that (for example) news from the foo department goes here and news from the bar department goes there - Sitefinity just knows that it's all news content.

Take a look here for a better look at the code behind a sitemap generator:
http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-12-22/new_sitefinity_4_4_sdk_sample_sitemap_module.aspx

Comment: thanks Craig O. I start learning sitefinty.

Comment: there are actually many examples in the SDK (linked in the post from Craig) to help you learn to develop with sitefinity. if you hit any snags be sure to post in the sitefinity forums or open up a support ticket. hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I'm generating sitemap content (pages, built-in, and dynamic) in Sitefinity 6.1.

Please note that ["Before you configure default pages for content items, you must configure canonical URLs service."](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/default-pages-for-content-items)

- **Pages**

  ```
  ISite currentSite = ((MultisiteContext) SystemManager.CurrentContext).CurrentSite;
  using (var manager = PageManager.GetManager())
  {
      var nodes = manager.GetPageNodes().Where(p =>
          p.RootNodeId == currentSite.SiteMapRootNodeId &&
          p.NodeType == Telerik.Sitefinity.Pages.Model.NodeType.Standard &&
          p.ShowInNavigation);
      foreach (var node in nodes)
      {
          if (!node.Page.IsBackend &&
              node.Page.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && 
              node.Page.Visible)
          {
              string host = getPageHost(serverPort, serverName, node.Page.RequireSsl);
              var url = string.Concat(host, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(node.GetFullUrl()));
              // Then append to sitemap
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Built-in content types - News example**

  ```
  using (var manager = NewsManager.GetManager())
  {
      var newsItems = manager.GetNewsItems().Where(p => 
          p.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && p.Visible).ToList();
      // append items
      foreach (var item in newItems)
      {
          var location = SystemManager.GetContentLocationService().GetItemDefaultLocation(item);
          if (location != null)
          {
              var fullUrl = location.ItemAbsoluteUrl;
              // Then append to sitemap (if page is live/visible/frontend)                    
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- **Dynamic content types**

  ```
  ISite currentSite = ((MultisiteContext) SystemManager.CurrentContext).CurrentSite;
  var providers = currentSite.GetProviders("YourModuleName").Select(p => p.ProviderName).ToList();
  foreach (string provider in providers)
  {       
      var dynamicType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Fully.Qualified.Name.Of.Your.Dynamic.Type");

      if (dynamicType != null)
      {
          using (var manager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(providerName))
          {
              var dynamicTypeItems = manager.GetDataItems(dynamicType).Where(p =>
                  p.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && p.Visible).ToList();
              foreach (var item in dynamicTypeItems)
              {
                  var location = SystemManager.GetContentLocationService().GetItemDefaultLocation(item);
                  if (location != null)
                  {
                      var fullUrl = location.ItemAbsoluteUrl;
                      // Then append to sitemap (if page is live/visible/frontend)                    
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```